# Stata: current date time like "yyyy-mm-dd H:m:s"

Tags: datetime, stata

I want to use Stata to output in a text file the current date/time in yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s format (like you can in php with date("Y-m-d H:i:s").

The time is already done with $S_TIME, but I can't seem to work around the format of $S_DATE to do it.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
. di %td_CY-N-D  date("$S_DATE", "DMY") " $S_TIME"
2013-12-13 13:58:55

. local wanted : di %td_CY-N-D  date("$S_DATE", "DMY") " $S_TIME"

. di "`wanted'"
   2013-12-13 14:00:27

. di trim("`wanted'")
2013-12-13 14:00:27
```

The first two displays are indented. `trim()` trims the leading spaces.

The trick here is that the global macro `S_DATE` is defined as a string. It has to be converted to a numeric date before a different format is possible.

The time lapse between the different times here is just mine in preparing this.